# Make magento admin panel iPhone accessible

Tags: iphone, magento, mobile

It appears the admin for magento is not iPhone accessible.  Whenever I try to access the control panel, it appears the javascript fails to open the drop down menus.  Does anyone know how to make it accessible via the iPhone or mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it does work. 
I just tried to enter the admin panel for one of our customers from my iPhone 3Gs, and all is working fine. I could see the orders, the configuration, etc. 
It was from a plain Safari browser.

Comment: This works because mobile safari turns a 'tap' event into a collection of 'mouseover', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click' events. It is the 'mouseover' event that shows the menu and since it isn't a link the 'click' does nothing negative.

Comment: for some reason several days ago when I tried this it didn't work.. now it does.. puzzling.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use opera mobile to get it going